# How can I use Castle container outside of MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I have setup an asp.net mvc 4 solution to use Castle Windsor as my DI container. I am using the log4Net facility with it too. I have set the container up in the global.asax as shown on the Windsor website...

```
private static IWindsorContainer container;

private static void BootstrapContainer()
{
    container = new WindsorContainer()
    .Install(FromAssembly.This());
    var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel);
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
}
```

I have installers setup and I am successfully injecting services into my controllers via the constructor. I am also successully using the log4Net facility in my controllers.

I would like to know how I can use the container to resolve the interface ILogger (the interface for the log4net component) outside of the controllers. For example, in a custom HandleError filter.

Comment: Actually I believe a quick read on Castle Windsor documentation will give you an auto-answer for you...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how well you understand the concept of DI. You need to implement the concept yourself. A DI container doesn't do that for you. As a bare minimum, implement this property and constructor in your `HandleError` class; this provides DI for that class and the logger can be injected.

```
private ILogger Logger { get; set; }

public HandleError(ILogger logger)
{
    Logger = logger;
}
```

The way you ask the question triggers a thought that you may have no idea how to allow the logger to be injected. If you don't provide DI, a DI container cannot do its job. Eventually, the bootstrapper is the (ideally only) place where you resolve dependencies.

Comment: Also, I guess you may want to up-skill on DI and DI containers. Do some research or watch this very straight forward tutorial: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/dependency-injection-on-ramp